# wordpress missing P tag

Tags: wordpress, post, format

I am creating a file outside of wordpress but i want to get wordpress post etc. I created the following which does whar i want it to do but it is missing th `P` tags. if i view this post through wp-admin it looks fine. if i view it through this function it doe snot look find

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');

//Global WordPress
global $wpdb;

if(!isset($wpdb))
{
    require_once('wp-config.php');
    require_once('wp-load.php');
    require_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}

$args = array("post_title" => $_GET['name'],"category_name"=>"knowledge-map");
$query = get_posts( $args );


$posttitle = $_GET['name'];
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $posttitle . "'" );
$post = $getpost= get_post($postid);

$post_title = sanitize_post_field( 'post_title', $post->post_title, $post->ID, 'display' );
$post_content = sanitize_post_field( 'post_content', $post->post_content, $post->ID, 'display' );

//$postcontent= $getpost->post_content;
//setup_postdata( $getpost );
$data = $post->post_content;
//foreach ( $getpost as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
    //$data = get_the_title() . the_content();  
//endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();


echo $data;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post_content` won't show proper formatting...basically ever. You need to apply `the_content` filter to it:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $data);
```

Here's where it's mentioned [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage).

While `wpautop` will only add paragraph tags where new lines exist, `the_content` runs a bunch of core filters (including `wpautop`). From [the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L131), `the_content` includes:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

Comment: whats the differene with `echo wpautop( $post_content );`?

Comment: `wpautop` will only apply formatting when there's a new line. The filter will also apply proper formatting to a bunch of other cases. See my edit above.

Comment: `wpautop` is included in `the_content` filters.

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it +1

Comment: `apply_filters` or `wpautop`?

Comment: @PieterGoosen was referring to `apply_filters` being better than `wpautop` in this situation.

Comment: @bonez all filters are applied to `post_content`. This filters are the same ones applied to `the_content()`. Definitely mevius approach here of `apply_filters`

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `wpauto`, it uses in wordpress for auto formatting of text

```
echo wpautop( $post_content );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very techy, but I found that if I copy everything from the "text" area in a Wordpress post, then paste it into a markdown to HTML editor, then it results in

tags being added wherever Wordpress omits them!

1. Copy the "Text" from a Wordpress post
2. Paste into markdown/HTML editor
3. View the HTML for that markdown